# How to use User.findOne({ userID: searchUserID } correctly ??? (currently not getting return value)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, crud

I am currently trying to implement an update / put functionality in my node.js-project and having issues I have absolutely no clue, where that comes from. (also I am a JS beginner). I am using express, MongoDB and mongoose.

Problem is in this method (or how I call it):

```
User.findOne({ userID: searchUserID })
```

Kontext of the the method, that is called:

```
/* find User by userID */ 
// calling sequence: UserService > findUserBy() callback

    function findUserBy(searchUserID, callback) {
        logger.debug(`UserService: searching for user with userID '${searchUserID}'...`)
        let query = User.findOne({ userID: searchUserID }) 
        query.exec(function (err, user) {/*content*/})
    }
```

When I call it directly from the UserRoute module like this:

```
/* get one user */
// calling sequence: UserRoute > router.get('/:userID') callback > userService.findUserBy() callback

    router.get('/:userID', function (req, res, next) {
        userService.findUserBy(req.params.userID, function (err, user) {/* content */})
    })
```

then it all works fine.

But when I want to use that function from another function inside the same module (`UserService`):

```
/* update one User */
// calling sequence: UserService > updateUser > findUserBy() callback

    function updateUser(userID, newUserData, callback) {
        findUserBy(userID, function (err, user) {...})
        let id = user.body.id
        /* more content */
    }
```

Then I am getting an error, since 'user' is not defined.

Obviously `User.findOne({ userID: searchUserID })` is working in the first case and returns a user. But it is not working in the second case.

I have used the debugger to check the parameters, that are delivered when calling the findOne function.

The 1st parameter is: searchUserID
and the value is: 'manfred'

The 2nd parameter is a callback function, but it doesn't come this far anyway.

The first parameter is exactly the same, no matter whether I call it directly from `UserRoute.js` or the `UserService.js`.

I have also compared the content of the 'query'-objects in both cases.
It has a bit more then 3700 lines and they have differences in like 10 lines... some veeeery long numbers that I don't understand. Probably random Numbers, timeStamps or ...I really have no clue (but if someone needs them I can look them up again).

Why is `User.findOne({ userID: searchUserID })` not working in the second case?

**EDIT**: my full functions (without shortening them with 'content)

in `UserService.js`:

```
//find User by userID
function findUserBy(searchUserID, callback) { //UserService > findUserBy() callback
    logger.debug(`UserService: searching for user with userID '${searchUserID}'...`)
    let query = User.findOne({ userID: searchUserID }) // query object erstellen
    query.exec(function (err, user) { //query wird asynchron ausgeführt
        if (err) {
            logger.error(err.message)
            return callback(err.message)  // callback übergibt fehlernachricht
        }
        if (user) {  // hier wirkt null wie false
            logger.debug(`Found userID: ${searchUserID}`)
            callback(null, user)
        }
        else {
            //logger.error("Did not find user for userID: " + searchUserID)
            callback(`Did not find user with userID: ${searchUserID}`, user)  // callback übergibt fehlernachricht
        };
    })
}
```

This one is not done yet, but that comes after:

```
    // update User
    function updateUser(userID, newUserData, callback) {
        logger.debug(`Updating user '${userID}'...`)
        findUserBy(userID, function (err, user) { //UserService>updateUser>findUserBy() callback
            if (user) {
                logger.debug(user)
                    (null, user.body)
            }
            else {
                logger.error(err)
                return console.log("Did not find any User with this userID" + [], null)
            }
        })
        //logger.debug("user:" + user, err)
        console.log("so far so good...")
        let id = user.body.id
        let user = new User()
        Object.assign(user, user.body)
        Object.assign(user, newUserData)
        user.body.id = id
        user.save(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                logger.debug("Could not create user account: " + err)
                return callback("Could not create user account", null)
            }
            else {
                callback(null, user)
            }
        })
    }
```

in `UserRoute.js`:

```
/* update one User */ 
    router.put('/:userID', function (req, res, next) {
        userService.updateUser(req.params.userID, req, function (err, user) {
            if (user) {
                //res.send(Object.assign(user))
                logger.debug(user)
                res.send(`User ${req.body.userID} sucessfully updated. \r\r new Json-Body: \r ` + user)
            }
            else {
                logger.error(err)
                res.send("Did not find any User with this userID" + [])
            }
        })
    })


/* get one user */
router.get('/:userID', function (req, res, next) {
    userService.findUserBy(req.params.userID, function (err, user) { //UserRoute > router.get('/:userID') callback > userService.findUserBy() callback
        if (user) {
            res.send(user)
            logger.debug(user)
            //res.json(user)
        }
        else {
            logger.error(err)
            res.send("Did not find any User with this userID" + [])
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to convert req.params.userID to an object Id
For eg :

`Types.ObjectId(req.params.uuid)`

also Import Types

```
import { Types } from 'mongoose'
```

Comment: The value of req.params.userID is just "manfred" in that call.
just like the value of 'userID' in the (non-working) case is "manfred" aswell.


when this is called:
User.findOne({ userID: searchUserID })

searchUserID == "manfred" either way.



Also:
req.params.userID

Is only beeing used in the function that calls correctly and works without issues. No need to change the working code. :-/

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because you try to access the data while you still fetching it from the DB.

My opinion: Dont use callbacks, they are pretty old and you will sooner or later land into an callback hell. Mongoose supports Promises. Rewrite your code a bit:

```
function findUserBy(searchUserID) {
    logger.debug(`UserService: searching for user with userID '${searchUserID}'...`)
    return User.findOne({ userID: searchUserID }).exec()
}
```

If you not provide an callback, your function will return an promise with either `null` or your user.

Lets rewrite your router a bit:

```
router.get('/:userID', async function (req, res, next) {
   let user = await userService.findUserBy(req.params.userID)
   console.log(user)
})
```

I made an `async / await` out of it. `await` only works in an async function and can await Promises.

If you do this now:

```
async function updateUser(userID, newUserData) {
    let user = await findUserBy(userID)
    if(!user) {
       console.log("no user found")
    }
    let id = user.body.id
    /* more content */
}
```

You should see some result. I made `updateUser` an async function. So you can use `await`. But watch out. Async function returns an promise, so you will also need to use `await` on them.

If you ever see an callback as second argument, then its most of the time asynchronouse code.

Edited code:

```
function findUserBy(searchUserID) {
  return User.findOne({ userID: searchUserID }).exec(); // query object erstellen
}

async function updateUser(userID, newUserData) {
  let user = await findUserBy(userID);
  if (!user) throw "Cannot find user";
  let newUser = new User({ ...user.body, ...newUserData });
  return newUser.save();
}

/* update one User */

router.put("/:userID", async function(req, res, next) {
  try {
    let user = await userService.updateUser(req.params.userID, req.body);
    res.status(200).json(user);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(404).json("Did not find any User with this userID" + []);
  }
});

/* get one user */
router.get("/:userID", async function(req, res, next) {
  try {
    let user = await userService.findUserBy(req.params.userID);
    if (!user)
      return res
        .status(404)
        .send("Did not find any User with this userID" + []);
    return res.status(200).json(user);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: I also thought this is the problem.
Especially before using the debugger and just reading this message:
"Cannot access 'user' before initialization"


But shouldn't it have worked then, aftter the debugger made it wait for minutes at several points?  ... still I got the same message...

Comment: Could I (as a quicker solution) just let the "query.exec(function (err, user) {/*content*/})"-Operation wait until the user is there?

How? :-S


Anyhow thanks for your answer so far.  I'm trying to figure that out (but thats something new to learn for me now..)

Comment: @LucasKnäuper well, i have created another version. I have edited my post